# What is the point of "create_clock" command in FPGA design?

Tags: verilog, clock, fpga

In FPGA programming, what is the point of using the create_clock command in the XDC (or UCF) file? Let's say I have a clock port CLK that is assigned to a physical pin (which is my clock), in the XDC (or UCF) file. Why can't I just go ahead and use this CLK pin in my top level HDL? Why do I need to add something like this:

```
create_clock -name sys_clk_pin -period "XXX" [get_ports "CLK"]
```

Also, let's say I have a main clock "CLK" and some other clocks which I generate in HDL. Do I have to use "create_clock" for all the minor clock in XDC too?

I don't get this whole "create_clock" thing. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Design constraints, as the name suggests, are used in order to define additional constraints of your design, which can't be captured from HDL description.

Lets take `create_clock` command as an example. You specified the clock pin in your HDL description, why isn't this enough? The reason is that clock signal is not a usual signal - it is used as a reference signal by a synchronous logic (flip-flops).

I suppose you're familiar with "propagation delay" (through logic gates) concept. You want to make sure  that all signals originating at one flop and sampled at the other will be able to propagate during a single clock cycle. Now, the total propagation delay you can know right after synthesis because each logic gate in FPGA has associated propagation delay (just sum these up). But how your analysis tools know what is the maximal allowed propagation delay? You do not specify these constraints in HDL, right? This is one of the cases where the frequency you specified with `create_clock` command will be used - it will be converted to period, and an analysis tool will warn you if any of the combinatorial paths in your design takes longer to propagate than clock's period.

The above example describes one of the actions performed by Static Timing Analysis (STA) tools in which "design constraints" are employed.

Another kind of tools which make extensive use of design constraints is Clock Domain Crossing (CDC) tools. These tools employed in designs containing more than one clock. The CDC concepts are described brilliantly [here](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276114)

In case you take one clock and generate another one from it (clock divider for example) you want to make CDC tool aware of this, because the fact that these clocks are related is important. Your way to inform CDC tool that the clocks are related is to use `create_generated_clock` constraint.

NOTE: the above examples are basic and by no means comprehensive.